# <jsp:setProperty name=“po” property=“*”/> is working fine in Internet Explorer, but in Firefox Browser some form values are not set to Bean

Tags: java, html, jsp, cross-browser, jsp-tags

**index.jsp**

```
    <body>
    <jsp:useBean id="po" scope="request" class="Forms.POInfoForm" />
    <form name="frmEntry" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" action="mediator.jsp" onSubmit = "return confirmSubmit();">
    <table border="3" bordercolor="#000000" id="tableName2" width="80%"> 
        <%  
        if (po.getBldgId() != null) {
            for (int j=0; j < po.getBldgId().length; j++) { 
            %>
                            
                            <input type="hidden" value="" name="bldgitemId">
                            <tr>
                                <td width="33%">
                                    <font color="#000000">  Building: </font>
                                    <div id="buildingInfo<%=j%>"/>
                                    <script language="JavaScript">
                                
                              createBuildingList(<%=j%>, buildingInfo<%=j%>, <%=po.getBldgId(j) %>);
                                    </script>

                            <td width="33%">
                                <font color="#000000">  Sub Account: </font>
                                <div id="subAccountInfo<%=j%>"/>
                                <script language="JavaScript">
createSubAccountList(<%=j%>, subAccountInfo<%=j%>, <%=po.getBldgId(j) %>, <%=po.getSubAccountId(j) %>);
                                
                            </script>
                             </td>
                             </tr>
                           </table>
```

by clicking the submit it will move to medaitor.jsp page where i seeting form values to a bean

**mediator.jsp**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
Mediator
</title>
</head>
<jsp:useBean id="po" scope="request" class="Forms.POInfoForm" />
<body bgcolor="#ffffff">
<h1>
Mediator JSP
</h1>

<jsp:setProperty name="po" property="*"/>
//some actions
```

the scripts in index.jsp page will generate below two select tags(when i inspect in browser)

[image]

**In internet explorer the bean is taking the form values, but in firefox bean is not taking above two form values.**

**Please help, thanks in advance!...**

Comment: If I see that correctly, your problem is in JavaScript right?

Comment: that script is generating two select tags correctly, but those two filed values are not set to bean in firefox